# React Native Expo Error. What should I do?

Tags: react-native, expo

### This is the Error :--

```sh
[stderr] AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux Daemon #7: Idle daemon unexpectedly exit. This should not happen.
Sat, 27 Feb 2021 18:14:51 GMT
[stderr] AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux Daemon #6: Idle daemon unexpectedly exit. This should not happen.
Sat, 27 Feb 2021 18:14:51 GMT
[stderr] AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux Daemon #5: Idle daemon unexpectedly exit. This should not happen.
Sat, 27 Feb 2021 18:14:51 GMT
[stderr] AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux Daemon #4: Idle daemon unexpectedly exit. This should not happen.
Sat, 27 Feb 2021 18:14:52 GMT
[stderr] AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux Daemon #1: Idle daemon unexpectedly exit. This should not happen.
Sat, 27 Feb 2021 18:14:52 GMT
[stderr] AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux Daemon #2: Idle daemon unexpectedly exit. This should not happen.
Sat, 27 Feb 2021 18:14:53 GMT
[stderr] AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux Daemon #3: Idle daemon unexpectedly exit. This should not happen.
Sat, 27 Feb 2021 18:14:53 GMT
[stderr] AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux Daemon #0: Idle daemon unexpectedly exit. This should not happen.
Sat, 27 Feb 2021 18:14:53 GMT
Error: ./gradlew exited with signal: SIGKILL
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:51:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:418:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:17:21)
    at spawnAsyncThrowError (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/ExponentTools.js:201:45)
    at buildShellAppAsync (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/AndroidShellApp.js:976:11)
    at async Object.createAndroidShellAppAsync (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/AndroidShellApp.js:396:5)
    at async runShellAppBuilder (/app/turtle/build/builders/android.js:95:9)
    at async Object.buildAndroid [as android] (/app/turtle/build/builders/android.js:43:28)
    at async build (/app/turtle/build/jobManager.js:181:33)
    at async processJob (/app/turtle/build/jobManager.js:118:32)
    at async Object.doJob (/app/turtle/build/jobManager.js:49:5)
    at async main (/app/turtle/build/server.js:66:13)
```

This error is with Expo React Native.

Everything was working fine until I ran the command `expo build:android`

Here is the URL to all of the [Logs](https://github.com/abhyuday-tripathi/logs/blob/master/README.md)

Abhyuday Tripathi

Comment: Did you found any solution? Same issue with me also.

Comment: Yeah I just edited my `app.json` and then I ran the command `expo build:android` and it worked fine. Now I have the apk file of the App

Comment: # Should I add the `app.json` file???

Comment: @AbhyudayTripathiwhat did you change in `app.json`? I'm also having the same issue

Comment: try removing versioncode/numbers from iOS and android in `app.json`. Worked after removing

Comment: Well... I didn't changed a thing. I just ran `expo build:android -t apk` again and everything worked.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I just closed and re-open the terminal and ran below command:

```
expo build:android -t apk
```

Answer (score 1):

Do nothing, just try again. It is not your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar error after updating my global Expo npm package.
For some reason, an app that would always build crashed during building with that error.

As I hadn't done any changes to the actual app, I deleted the app/project from
expo.io, and rebuilt it with the `expo build` command. This made the build succeed.

I'm just leaving this here as an answer, in case someone runs into the same error after updating Expo.

Answer (score 0):

First time I had this problem, reason was I've used an invalid slug name in app.json, there must be a dash between the words as below :

```
  "expo": {   
    "slug": "My-App",
```

After a while I had the same problem,

1. I've realized that my expo-cli version wasn't latest one, I've
   updated it
2. Just closed and re-opened the VS Code and terminal as
   Zain said above in this page